# Reading a file to a list, and printing it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a text file and append its data to a list, which is then printed.
I am having difficulties however, because when I print the list, it is empty, when the code to me clearly has the text file data appended to it.

I have read similar questions and tried to replicate their outcomes, but to no avail.

Can any of you see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the important snippet of my code:

```
def parse_feed(rss_url):
    ''' This function parses the Yahoo! RSS API for data of the latest five articles, and writes it to companyNews.txt'''

# Define the RSS feed to parse from, as the url passed in of the company the user chose
    feed = feedparser.parse(rss_url)

# Define the file to write the news data to, companyNews.txt
    outFile = open('companyNews.txt', mode='w')

# Create a list to store the news data parsed from the Yahoo! RSS
    news_data_write = []
# Initialise a count
    count = 0
# For the number of articles to append to the file, append the article's title, link, and published date to the news_elements list
    for i in range(2):
        news_data_write.append({feed['entries'][count].title,
                      feed['entries'][count].link,
                      feed['entries'][count].published})
# Add one to the count, so that the next article is parsed
        count+=1
# For each item in the news_elements list, convert it to a string and write it to companyNews.txt
        for item in news_data_write:
            item = str(item)
            outFile.write(item)
# For each article, write a new line to companyNews.txt, so that each article's data is on its own line
        outFile.write('\n')
        print(news_data_write)
# Clear the news_elements list so that data is not written to the file more than once
        del(news_data_write[:])

        read_news_file()

def read_news_file():


    with open('companyNews.txt', mode='r') as inFile:
        news_data = inFile.read()

    news_data_list = news_data.splitlines()

    print(news_data_list)
```

Comment: Maybe the out-file is not yet flushed when you are reading it? Just a guess...

Comment: Instead of `for i in range(2):` and then `count+=1`, why not just `for count in range(2):`?

Comment: you should with open the outFile too, it's just better :)

Comment: All those loops don't make any sense to me. Why do you erase the list in between writes? Why not just write after the loop? And why loop over entries if the list can only ever contain one element?

Comment: I erase between writes so that I do not double-write data. If I didn't, the text file would be as follows: LINE 1 'the quick brown fox', LINE 2 'the quick brown fox' 'jumped over the lazy dog'. If you at all understand that.

Comment: The problem is that you do not flush or close the `outfile` before try to reading it., as epressed by @tobias_k.

Comment: @Nick I understand that, but that's just because you write _all the lines you read so far_ after _each line you read_. If you want to write just the line you read last anyway, don't use a list. Or just write all the lines after the `for i` loop.

Comment: Could it be a scope error? Do you need to define `news_data` before the `with` statement?